# Compactness of Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, compactness, propositional-calculus

I little confused on compactness of propositional logic.

So propositional logic has the property of being compact, that is to say, given a set of formulas $\mathcal F$, then $\mathcal F$ is satisfiable if and only if every finite subset of $\mathcal F$ is satisfiable.

But what about the following: If $\mathcal F = \{F_0, F_1, \ldots \}$ such that

$F_0$ = there are finitly many things in the universe.

$F_1$ = there is at least one thing in the universe.

$F_2$ = there are at least two things in the universe.

.

.

.

$F_n$ = there are at least $n$ things in the universe.

Clearly $\mathcal F$ is not satisfiable even though every finite subset is satisfiable. Does that mean $\mathcal F$ is not in propositional logic? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you cannot express $F_0$ in propositional logic.

In fact, in *propositional* logic, there's no real *universe* of objects - models of propositional languages are simply assignments of truth values to atomic formulas - so you can't really speak about "how many things there are" at all.

You *can* do so, however, in *predicate* logic. For example, "There are at least $n$ things" can be expressed as $$
  \varphi_n = \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n \,:\, x_1 \neq x_2 \land \ldots \land x_1 \neq x_n \land x_2 \neq x_3 \land \ldots \land x_2 \neq x_n \land \ldots 
$$
and "There are at most $n$ things as $$
  \theta_n = \lnot \varphi_{n+1} 
$$

But even in predicate logic, how would you express "There are finitely many things"? You can't use $$
  \theta_1 \lor \theta_2 \lor \ldots
$$
because that formula would have infinite length.

In fact you can extend the reasoning in your question, by applying it to first-order *predicate* logic instead, to rigorosly prove that $F_0$ isn't expressible in first-order predicate logic.

Comment: Note that $\exists$ is not part of the symbols of propositional calculus.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Arg! I keep mixing up the english expressions "propositional logic" and "predicate logic". Dunno why, really, they're similar enough to the german expressions. But anway, in *propositional logic*, can we talk about "how many things there are" at all? Models, in this case, just assign truth values to propositions, no - so the concept of the *size* of a universe doesn't have any meaning, no?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In propositional logic we only have "binary" variables which can be either true or false. We don't really have a universe with objects.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks! So I'm not totally confused ;-) I've fixed my answer to correctly distinguish between the propositional and the predicate case, hopefully I didn't make any other silly mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is that you can't really express $F_0$ using propositional logic (or first-order logic for that matter).

For the matter of fact, propositional calculus is unable to express existence either, since quantifiers are not part of its language.

Comment: But why is that true? I mean I can say $F_0$ says "for all natural numbers $n$, there exists a subset of all things in the universe such that its size is greater than $n$" Or is that not first-order logic?

Comment: But the natural numbers are not part of your language. How do you quantify over them? Your idea won't even work, if anything "There exists a natural number $n$ such that there are exactly $n$ things in the universe", my point is still valid: we can't quantify over the natural numbers like that.